# Add Web browser data to a string using Python

Tags: python

[About Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30vkF.png)

[Store Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxXZO.png)

Hi I would like to know how you can extract html / webbrowser data

So I can add it to a string

Comment: What have your tried / researched? Do you just need the raw text or do you need further processing? The lack of this information is likely why you query has been down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
r = requests.get(“http://somesite.com”)
print(r.text)
```

you can save r.text into a variable... perform split function on it to put into a list... or use regular expressions to extract data between tags... there's a million possibilities once you have that string. Have fun!

Comment: I tried this but it seems like the request.get gives back the same information regardless of whether your tabbed on About or Store